# Apache Mod Rewrite change querystring to "Folder Structure"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Grettings everyone.

I have a current url: 
http://localhost/product/?product_id=12&slug=state-of-trance-2011

I need to change it to:
http://localhost/product/12/state-of-trance-2011

Whats the best way of accomplishing this?

Regards

Comment: this has been asked many times, consider search in the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this code in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ product/?product_id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```